# Samba file mask calculation on ACL - missing r

Tags: samba, access-control-list, mask

I would like to ask a detail how samba deals with permission on ACL on servers. I did dig very hard and deep but no luck with this one. I have set ACL support over this think and again, regardles of all I red a bit is missing. Let me ask below the code.

I have got a directory spolecne (this is the samba share):

```
# file: spolecne/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
group:amikon:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:amikon:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

samba share set as:

```
[spolecne]
path = /smb/spolecne
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = no
writable = yes
valid users = @amikon
```

and entries created from windows machine looks this way (vanek is a member of amikon):

```
# file: dir
# owner: vanek
# group: amikon
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:amikon:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:amikon:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

# file: file.txt
# owner: vanek
# group: amikon
user::rwx
group::-w-      //read is missing
group:amikon:rwx
mask::rwx
other::-w-      //read is missing
```

The dir looks as expected. While default directory mask is 777 I got 777. I expected this behavior.

The trouble is the file. Create mask is 777 and I expected x bit from group and other to be removed. But the result is that r and x was removed.

So the question is whether you guys could explaine to me why the read bit was removed???

I really appriciate any help as I spend best part of my life with this.